# Encoding audio to matroska container using ffmpeg audio encoder adpcm_adx

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, video-streaming

Trying to reencode audio file from mp4 container to Matroska(mkv) container using FFmpeg audio encoder adpcm_adx or (aptx, comfortnoise, g726le...) I am getting an error message

```
No wav codec tag found for codec ...
```

I have c++ code which includes thired-party integration of ffmpeg,
and I am having the same result using ffmpeg terminal options.

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a adpcm_adx -b:a 44100 output.mkv
```

Instead of getting output file correctly I am getting

```
No wav codec tag found for codec adpcm_adx
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Conversion failed!
```

Maybe I should specify extra parameters for making it work which I haven't hooked up yet. 
Thanks in advance.
I'll appreciate any help.